# EsxCliElementImpl doesn't contain a method 'install'

Tags: installation, powercli

I'm getting the following error while trying to install a VIB using powershell script via powerCLI.

> PowerCLI C:\vib> .\vib_ESXi_script.ps1
>  Installing VIB on
>   [x.x.x.x]
>  Method invocation failed because
>   [VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Impl.V1.EsxCli.EsxCliElementImpl] doesn't
>   contain a method named 'install'.
>  At
>   C:\vib\vib_ESXi_script.ps1:233 char:1
>   + $action = $ESXCLI.software.vib.install($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$true,$null
>   ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (install:String) [], RuntimeEx    ception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

I've checked to see if powercli module is installed and it is there:

PowerCLI C:\vib> Get-Module -Name VMware.* -ListAvailable


    Directory: C:\WindowsPowerShell\Modules


ModuleType Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- ----                                ----------------
Manifest   VMware.PowerCLI
Script     VMware.Vim
Script     VMware.VimAutomation.Nsxt           {Connect-NsxtServer, Disconne...
Script     VMware.VimAutomation.Srm            {Connect-SrmServer, Disconnec...
Script     VMware.VimAutomation.StorageUtility Update-VmfsDatastore
Script     VMware.VimAutomation.Vmc            {Connect-Vmc, Disconnect-Vmc,...


    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\Infrastructure\PowerCLI\Modules


ModuleType Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- ----                                ----------------
Binary     VMware.DeployAutomation
Binary     VMware.ImageBuilder
Binary     VMware.VimAutomation.Cis.Core
Binary     VMware.VimAutomation.Cloud
Manifest   VMware.VimAutomation.Common
Binary     VMware.VimAutomation.Core           HookGetViewAutoCompleter
Binary     VMware.VimAutomation.HA
Binary     VMware.VimAutomation.HorizonView
Binary     VMware.VimAutomation.License
Binary     VMware.VimAutomation.PCloud
Manifest   VMware.VimAutomation.Sdk            Get-PSVersion
Binary     VMware.VimAutomation.Storage
Binary     VMware.VimAutomation.Vds
Binary     VMware.VimAutomation.vROps
Binary     VMware.VumAutomation


My code is:

```
$ESXCLI = Get-EsxCli -VMHost $hostName -V2

$action = $ESXCLI.software.vib.install($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$true,$null,$null,$VIBPATH)
```

I've checked to see if the method is actually supported:

> PowerCLI C:\vib> $ESXCLI.software.vib
>  
>   ==================
>  EsxCliElement: vib
>  
>     Elements:
>     ---------
>     signature
>
> Method Elements:
>     ---------
>     get
>     install
>   list
>     remove
>     update
>
> Methods:
>     --------
>     string Help()

Comment: I believe the v2 method uses invoke() instead. i.e if I do,  $esxcli.network.nic.list() I get an error but if I do  $esxcli.network.nic.list.invoke() I get a result

Comment: https://www.virten.net/2016/11/how-to-use-esxcli-v2-commands-in-powercli/

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to go about correcting the issue. Either remove the `-v2` parameter from what you have, or keep it (recommended) and update the second part of your script to be something like the following:

```
$args = $esxcli.software.vib.install.CreateArgs()
$args.viburl = $VIBPATH #This is an assumption on my part on what the variable is referencing 
$esxcli.software.vib.install.invoke($args)
```

More information on using the `v2` parameter is available in the following link: https://blogs.vmware.com/PowerCLI/2016/04/powercli-6-3-r1-get-esxcli-why-the-v2.html

Comment: The above mentioned method fixed the no install method issue. However, now it complains about String module.  [VibDownloadError]
module 'string' has no attribute 'letters'

Comment: Output of "Get-Module -ListAvailable | Format-Table -Property Name,Version" does not list String.

Comment: I've run the above mentioned commands on command instead of script and I think the issue lies in @args.viburl line. This is what I see: Property 'viburl' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is
settable.